Angular Mirco frontend caching Issue - "ChunkLoadError"
I have a project which has 3 Shell apps and a Main app.

3 shell apps are agent-mfe, master-mfe, notification-mfe
the main app is the main-frontend

let's assume here When the user First goes to the main-frontend and from there calls the Shell apps... when the user Loads the one micro frontend (agent-mfe) by selecting an option inside nav and then again select another by side nav (master-mfe) and lets this at last user select the option which is in  notification-mfe then user try to select an option in previously loaded service it is tring to fined the .js file in lastly loaded notification-mfe not in the previously loaded service.
if I refresh the web page it load as expected.
main-frontend Project webpack.config.json Code
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");

const fs = require("fs");


const envFile = path.join(__dirname, 'src/environments/environment.ts');
const envContent = fs.readFileSync(envFile, { encoding: 'utf8' });

const masterDataBaseUrl = envContent.match(/masterDataBaseUrl: '(.*)'/)[1];
const agentServiceBaseUrl = envContent.match(/agentServiceBaseUrl: '(.*)'/)[1];
const notificationServiceBaseUrl = envContent.match(/notificationServiceBaseUrl: '(.*)'/)[1];


const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]
);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "mainFrontend",
    publicPath: "auto",
    scriptType: "text/javascript"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      remotes: {
        "agentsMfe": "agentsMfe@"+`${agentServiceBaseUrl}`+"/remoteEntry-agent.js",
        "masterDataMfe": "masterDataMfe@"+`${masterDataBaseUrl}`+"/remoteEntry-masterData.js",
        "notificationsMfe": "notificationsMfe@"+`${notificationServiceBaseUrl}`+"/remoteEntry-notification.js",
      },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};



in Side nav we can select Some options
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {loadRemoteModule} from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";

export const CommonLayout_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'notification-settings',
    loadChildren: async () => {
      try {
        const m = await loadRemoteModule({
          remoteEntry: `${environment.notificationServiceBaseUrl}/remoteEntry-notification.js`,
          remoteName: 'notificationsMfe',
          exposedModule: './NotificationSettingsModule'
        });
        return m.NotificationSettingsModule;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Notification micro frontend module loading fail", err);
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'agent',
    loadChildren: async () => {
      try {
        const m = await loadRemoteModule({
          remoteEntry: `${environment.agentServiceBaseUrl}/remoteEntry-agent.js`,
          remoteName: 'agentsMfe',
          exposedModule: './AgentModule'
        });
        return m.AgentModule;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Agent micro frontend module loading fail", err);
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'business-grouping',
    loadChildren: async () => {
      try {
        const m = await loadRemoteModule({
          remoteEntry: `${environment.masterDataBaseUrl}/remoteEntry-masterData.js`,
          remoteName: 'masterDataMfe',
          exposedModule: './BusinessGroupingModule'
        });
        return m.BusinessGroupingModule;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Master data micro frontend module loading fail", err);
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'distribution-channel',
    loadChildren: async () => {
      try {
        const m = await loadRemoteModule({
          remoteEntry: `${environment.agentServiceBaseUrl}/remoteEntry-agent.js`,
          remoteName: 'agentsMfe',
          exposedModule: './DistributionChannelModule'
        });
        return m.DistributionChannelModule;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Agent micro frontend module loading fail", err);
      }
    },
    data: {
      title: 'Distribution Channel',
      breadcrumb: 'Distribution Channel',
    }
  },
];


Considering above code Think user first select the option notification-settings when User selects that it loads like
notification service loading in Network call Screenshot remoteEntry-notifcation
then when user selects the option agent it loads like
agent service loading in Network call Screenshot remoteEntry-agent
then when user selects the option business-grouping it loads like
master data service loading in Network call Screenshot remoteEntry-mansterData
after that when user try to load an option in  remoteEntry-agent or remoteEntry-notifcation it gives an error. as an example I'll show try to call agent service
Console error that gives when Try to load a option in remoteEntry-agent
I tried to change the webpack.config.js code like
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },

to
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true
  },

I did this in main app and all the shell apps when I do that even Ui's didn't load.

I can reproduce it with a quick reload followed by the keyboard command ctrl+shirt+r while hitting the refresh button. Make sure to enable the preserve console log. I'm not sure what end user will do that normally. Not giving the App enough time to reload fully will cause the issue.
